# filter a vector of boost variant into a new vector?

Tags: c++, boost, variant, boost-variant

I am looking for the best way to filter a vector of the boost variant which has been defined like this:

```
 boost::variant<T1*, T2, T3> Var;
 std::vector<Var> Vec;
```

when I call this vector, what is the best way to filter only T2 bounded type and insert into new vector?
or in other way, I want something like this

```
std::vector<T2> T2Vec = ...(how to filter it from Vec)....
```

thank you!

EDIT: 
Since using a "visitor" is more robust, I'm also wondering of anyone could give me a solution using "visitor"?

thanks again!

Comment: You can use a similar approach as juanchopanza's original, using `std::remove_copy_if` and a functor that returns true when `v.which()!=1`.

Comment: @cv_and_he unfortunately, my initial approach is flawed: there is no conversion operator from `Var` to `T2`. What would be needed is a `transform_if` algorithm, which doesn't exist. I reverted to a plain loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to loop over `Vec`, checking if the element is a `double`, then push the double into a `T2Vec`. This is a C++03 version:

```
for (std::vector<Var>::const_iterator it = Vec.begin(); it != Vec.end(); ++it)
{
  if (it->which() == 1) T2Vec.push_back(boost::get<T2>(*it));
}
```

C++11 version:

```
for (const auto& v : Vec)
{
  if (v.which() == 1) T2Vec.push_back(boost::get<T2>(v));
}
```

Comment: @H'H sorry, `Vec2` should be `T2Vec`. `v` is an element of `Vec`.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately std version that I'm working with does not support std::copy_if

Comment: @H'H I replaced my previous version with a simple C++03 compliant loop.

Comment: dear juanchopanza,  I read the boost tutorial the mentioned that using boost::get<T>, the errors are detectable only at runtime check, can I also use bood::apply visitor for more robust result?